# Does bare-metal coreos etcd2 support the templating feature of coreos-cloudinit?

Tags: coreos

> If the platform environment supports the templating feature of
>   coreos-cloud it is possible to automate etcd configuration with the
>   `$private_ipv4` and `$public_ipv4` fields.
>   
> ...
>   Note: The `$private_ipv4` and `$public_ipv4` substitution variables
>   referenced in other documents are only supported on Amazon EC2, Google
>   Compute Engine, OpenStack, Rackspace, DigitalOcean, and Vagrant.

- [CoreOS Documentation](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html#etcd2)

If I run this on bare-metal, does this mean that I have to set the IP addresses manually?  The values won't be replaced?  And if so, how would I do that?

Comment: I read that there is a plugin for nginx that will serve it up and replace the values, but you have to pull your cloud config from there; and if you do that, you also have to use PXE to ghost the machines.

Comment: As true as that is, following the documentation hasn't worked for me, either with nginx < 1.9 or nginx > 1.9:
https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/nginx-host-cloud-config.html

I'll update this thread when I find a solution.